# Spring integration mail sets flag 'Flagged' after fetching email. Is there anyway to stop it from doing this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to fetch emails based on SearchTerms like from, subject and body and I have implemented `SearchTermStrategy` interface which takes
java mail `SearchTerm[]` as constructor argument and I also have extended `ImapMailReceiver` class and override its `searchForNewMessages()`. here is the code

```java
public class SearchTermStrategyImpl implements SearchTermStrategy {

    private final SearchTerm[] searchTerms;

    public SearchTermStrategyImpl(SearchTerm[] searchTerms) {
        this.searchTerms = searchTerms;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags supportedFlags, Folder folder) {
        SearchTerm searchTerm = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                searchTerm = searchTerms[i];
            } else {
                searchTerm = new AndTerm(searchTerm, searchTerms[i]);
            }
        }
        return searchTerm;
    }
}
```

overridden method of ImapMailReceiver

```java
@Override
protected Message[] searchForNewMessages() throws MessagingException {
    Message[] messages = null;
    Folder folder = getFolder();
    super.setSearchTermStrategy(searchTermStrategy);
    SearchTerm searchTerm = searchTermStrategy.generateSearchTerm(null, null);
    if (folder.isOpen()) {
        messages = searchTerm==null ? folder.getMessages() : folder.search(searchTerm);
    } else {
        throw new ImapException("Folder is closed");
    }
    return messages.length > 0 ? messages : new Message[0];
}
```

I have also set `SimpleContent`, `ShouldMarkMessagesAsRead` and `AutoCloseFolder` values as false of `ImapMailReceiver`.

At the end, i got message in payload which has additional flag 'Flagged', which is not right. Is there anyway to keep emails Flags as it is?

I have tried setting Flag.Flagged to false on each messages but it would be wrong in two ways

1. if user has flagged some of emails that are important.
2. By iterating over all emails and setting Flagged as false which will be a big performance hit and wrong as above.

I think, extra processing after fetching emails can be reduced in a situation where `SelectorExpression` is not specified (avoid call to `searchAndFilterMessages()` method )

Answer (score 0):

`Flags.Flag.FLAGGED` is set (in `AbstractMailReceiver.setMessageFlags()`) if the server doesn't support both `Flags.Flag.RECENT` and `Flags.Flag.USER`.

(These flags are used in the default search term).

It looks like you should be able to override `setAdditionalFlags()` and use `message.getFlags().removeFlag(Flags.Flag.FLAGGED)` (after calling `super.SetAdditionalFlags()` which sets `Flags.Flag.SEEN`).

Comment: I already did that but if there are lots of emails then it cause performance hit so i tried setting maxFetchSize so that it will fetch only specified number of emails but they come in ascending order. I think, there should be an option to choose whether user wants emails in ascending or descending order. Should i raise GH issue for improvements?

Comment: I don't think IMAP has an option for that. Maybe you could add a `ReceivedDateTerm` to your search strategy and keep track of the last read that way?